# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67 on laravel using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

This view has a link which calls a javascript function

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Opción</th>
        </tr>
    @foreach ($tasks as $task)
        <tr>
          <td>{{$task->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$task->name}}</td>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="eliminar({{$task->id}})" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </table>
@stop
```

and here is the javascript code

```
function eliminar(id){
  $.ajax({

           type: "DELETE",
           url: "task/"+id,
           success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
           },
           error: function (data) {
               alert('Error:', data);
           }
    });
}
```

and with the ajax call i want to call the destroy method of my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Task;

class TaskController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $tasks = Task::all();
        return view('mainview',['tasks' => $tasks]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        return "destroy";
    }
}
```

But when I click the links  I get this error :

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67

I'm new on Laravel but I thought that csrf was for forms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should add `csrf_field` to your main blade :

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Then add `_token` to your request :

```
var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

function eliminar(id){
  $.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: "task/"+id,
    data: { _token : _token },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
      alert('Error:', data);
    }
  });
}
```

Or you could add it one time in `ajaxSetup` and it will affect all calls to `$.ajax` or Ajax-based derivatives such as `$.get()` :

```
$.ajaxSetup(
{
    headers:
    {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
    }
});
```

Take a look to **[CSRF Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection)**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me. I found several answers online and none of them alone worked; however, after combining all, I got the Ajax call to go through.

1. In the head of your view file, add the following line:

   ```
   <meta name="csrf-token" content="<?php echo csrf_token() ?>"> // This will retrieve the necessary token.
   ```
2. Then, retrieve the value of the token and place it on a variable (optional step):

   ```
   var currentToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
   ```
3. On your ajax call, include the value of the token in the 'data:' field:

   ```
   $.ajax({type: 'POST', data: {_token:currentToken},....});
   ```

You may avoid the optional step of creating a new variable to it on the 'data:' field; however, I find this step easier to understand.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the token input field when passing the 'DELETE' method.

Html:

```
<input class="token" value="{{ csrf_field() }}"/>
```

Code:

```
function eliminar(id){
  var formData = '_token=' + $('.token').val();
  $.ajax({
           type: "DELETE",
           url: "task/"+id,
           data: formData,
           success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
           },
           error: function (data) {
               alert('Error:', data);
           }
    });
}
```

You could also remove that route from the verification process by adding it to the except array in the Middleware.