# How can I put ajax in global js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3

My view like this :

```
<input type="file" style="display: none" id="test">
```

When the file called, it will call ajax

I put my ajax in main.js (myshop\resources\assets\js\main.js)

It is global js. I put all my js there. I also put my ajax there

I put my ajax in main.js like this :

```
var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
console.log(_token);
$('#test').on("change", function(){ 
    data = new FormData();
    $.ajax({
        url: window.Laravel.baseUrl+'/product/addImage',
        type: "POST",
        data: { data: data, _token: _token },
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

My routes like this :

```
Route::post('product/addImage', 'ProductController@addImage');
```

My controller like this :

```
public function addImage(Request $request)
{ 
    dd('test');
    // dd($request->all());
}
```

When executed, the console tab exist error like this :

> POST http://myshop.dev/product/addImage 500 (Internal Server Error)

and on the network tab exist error like this :

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:

How can I solve the error?

Whether ajax can be placed in global js?

Comment: Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663432/tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken-php-line-67-on-laravel-using-ajax

Comment: @eeya, Look at my question. I had update it follow the reference. But it's the same. Whereas when I `console.log(_token);`, the token exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve  this issue in two ways:

You could use

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" /> // add this under head tag
And before Ajax call add this:-
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers:
    {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Or the other (simpler) way, inside your `app\Http\Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` add

```
protected $except = [
    'product/addImage',
];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Really like the first approach, I've been defining _token inside a script tag inside ***.blade.php since I started laravel. That seems sooo much cleaner

Comment: @kunal, I try you first way. It works. No error. But when I add `dd($_FILES);` in addImage method, the response display array empty like this : `[]`. Should it display array of photo uploaded

Comment: you have to add the name attribute in your <input type="file" name="image" >

Comment: @TrendingNews because your Form Data is empty, you need to append to the form data before it is send to the controller

Comment: @kunal, No. I use Laravel. So in my form like this : `{!! Form::open(['url' => 'product/store', 'files' => true]) !!}`. But I had define `enctype="multipart/form-data">` in my ajax. Look at my ajax

Comment: look at @SérgioReis answer it might help!

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your help guys

Comment: glad we are help you!

Answer (score 1):

Remember to add file to data

```
data = new FormData();
data.append("test", $("#fileInput")[0].files[0])
```